# Which exception should this throw?

Tags: java, exception

## Background

I am polishing my Java chops, preparing to take the Oracle Java 8 exam, and I've run across something puzzling. I've got something basic like this, that assumes there will be two values passed as arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String val1 = args[0];
        String val2 = args[1];
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) { // <-- Here is where it gets tricky
        ...
    }
}
```

I realize it's bad form to catch `Exception`, but, when I pass in bad data, I'm getting two different specific exceptions, depending on what I do with the generic `Exception` object, so I don't know which I need to catch here.

## Setup

If I do this:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
}
```

I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which makes sense, given `args` is an array.

However, if I do this instead:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, <strike>which also makes sense, given there's a reference to a String object in `args` that isn't there</strike> which doesn't make sense anymore, since there *should* be a cause.

## Question

*Which exception should be thrown here?*

Comment: This could throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since you might not pass enough args

Comment: You're probably getting a new `NullPointerException` because `e.getCause()` is null.

Comment: @Chris no, forget the `Integer.parseInt()` part. The exception is when I don't give the program any arguments. I'll edit out that to show what I'm really asking.

Comment: That doesn't throw NPE because of `args`. Values in `args` will never be `null`. `getCause` returns `null` if there is no cause. Calling `getMessage` on `null` throws a NPE.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but there _is_ a cause, if I just call `.toString()` it shows it.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Are you talking about `e.getCause().toString()`?

Comment: You call `toString` on _what_? The `e`? That's the exception caught by your `catch`. It doesn't have a `cause`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is `Exception` not `Throwable`?

Comment: Of course it is. Perhaps you're confused by what a `Throwable`'s `cause` is. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) the javadoc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not confused by what a `Throwable` is, or what its `cause` is. If I just print `e.getMessage()` it returns 0 (if I don't pass any arguments).

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It's not showing the actual exception. The real exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. So why is it just showing `0`?

Comment: You printed its message. Why did you except the exception class name to be printed? The message for that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is the index you tried to access that was out of bounds.

Comment: Because the message of an exception is different to the exception type. e.getMessage obviously gets the message of the exception. `new RuntimeException("I M Weasel")` <- Type is RuntimeException but "I M Weasel" is the message.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ah. enlightenment. I didn't realize the message was the index. I've learned something today. Thank you. :o)

Comment: That's the default JVM behavior. You can instantiate `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and initialize it with your own message (or a default one with an index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try amending the method like below and debug, step by step: -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String val1 = args[0];
        String val2 = args[1];
    } catch (Exception e) { // <-- Here is where it gets tricky
        System.err.println(e.toString());
        Throwable thr = e.getCause();
        String msg = thr.getMessage();
        System.err.println(msg);
    }
}
```

The only Exception thrown from the try clause is the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

In the catch clause, you will find that e.getCause() returns null because there is no other causal exception underlying the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Therefore, When you then try tocall getMessage() on the null cause, you get a NullPointerException.